# How to Deserialize in Boo language

Tags: boo

Why does the second line give an error?

```
items = serializer.DeserializeObject(json)
value = items ["key"]
```

Error: Type 'object' does not support slicing. (BCE0048)

I tried various ways to indicate that "items" is a dictionary, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
items as Dictionary [of string, object] = serializer.DeserializeObject(json)
```